# How Do I Build CloudWatch Alarms With AWS Amplify Custom?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

I believe I am encountering an issue where the [CloudWatch Alarms Actions library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch-actions) at 1.202.0 is not up to date with the CloudWatch library, at version 1.59.0, and Typescript is throwing an error.

I am building with [AWS Amplify Custom resources](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/custom/cdk/#reference-amplify-generated-resources).

**Code:**

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as sns from '@aws-cdk/aws-sns';
import * as subs from '@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions';
import * as cw from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch';
import * as cwa from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch-actions';

export class cdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create SNS topic
    const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'Topic', {
      displayName: 'Alarm topic',
    });

    // Add Email Subscription to SNS Topic
    topic.addSubscription(new subs.EmailSubscription("email@example.org"));

    // Define Lambda function's error metric
    const functionErrorMetric = new cw.Metric({
      namespace: 'AWS/Lambda',
      metricName: 'Errors',
      dimensions: { FunctionName: 'functionNameExample' },
      statistic: 'Sum',
    });

    // Create a CloudWatch Alarm
    const alarm = new cw.Alarm(this, 'Alarm', {
      metric: functionErrorMetric,
      threshold: 1,
      evaluationPeriods: 1,
      datapointsToAlarm: 1,
      comparisonOperator: cw.ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO_THRESHOLD,
    });

    // Add SNS topic as an action on Alarm state
    alarm.addAlarmAction(new cwa.SnsAction(topic));
  }
}
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "custom-resource",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper": "^2.0.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch-actions": "^1.202.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-iam": "^1.159.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sns": "^1.159.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions": "^1.159.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-sqs": "^1.159.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "^1.159.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

**Error Message:**

Note, the red squiggly underlines are at this line `alarm.addAlarmAction(new cwa.SnsAction(topic));`

```
Argument of type 'SnsAction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IAlarmAction'.
  Types of property 'bind' are incompatible.
    Type '(_scope: Construct, _alarm: IAlarm) => AlarmActionConfig' is not assignable to type '(scope: Construct, alarm: IAlarm) => AlarmActionConfig'.
      Types of parameters '_scope' and 'scope' are incompatible.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an effective workaround for this specific situation by creating a separate AWS CDK stack, independent from AWS Amplify custom resources.

**I defined an SNS Topic:**

```
// Create SNS topic
const topic = new Topic(this, "Topic", { displayName: "Alarm topic" });
topic.addSubscription(new EmailSubscription("example@example.com"));
```

**I utilized getContext to find the context of the branch to match the environment:**

```
import "source-map-support/register";
import { App } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import gitBranch from "git-branch";
import { CDKContext } from "../types";

// Obtaining the context of the environment, via the cdk.json file. This will allow us to dynamically name for "dev" and "prod"
export const getContext = async (app: App): Promise<CDKContext> => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const currentBranch = await gitBranch();
      const environment = app.node.tryGetContext("environments").find((e: any) => e.branchName === currentBranch);
      const globals = app.node.tryGetContext("globals");
      return resolve({ ...globals, ...environment });
    } catch (error) {
      return reject();
    }
  });
};
```

**I obtained the lambda resources through their name:**

```
const lambdaFunctionExample = LambdaFunction.fromFunctionName(this, `lambdaFunctionExample-${context.environment}`, `lambdaFunctionExample-${context.environment}`);
```

This approach allowed me to bypass the versioning issue and accomplish the task. I hope this solution helps anyone encountering the same problem. I only have a `dev` and `prod` environment, so this worked well with the naming convention provided by AWS Amplify.

Comment: I haven't put everything here, so add a comment if you need more support.